# How do I show home page if user has a valid session?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

How do I show a show home page if a user requests login page with a valid session using spring security?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(session == null) {
   // not valid
} else {
   String username = (String) request.getParameter("username");
   String age = (String) request.getParameter("age");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you load the login page, check for a valid session. If a valid session exists, then you can redirect the page to your home page. Where as if there is no session, you can continue with display of login screen.